# Synonym request: [source-to-source] and [transpiler]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

I recently created the [source-to-source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/source-to-source) tag for questions about [source-to-source compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpiler) and attempted to make it a synonym of the [transpiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transpiler) tag, but I do not have enough reputation to create tag synonyms for it. Should this tag request be completed?

Comment: And no-one will be able to given it's contained on only one question. Is `source-to-source` to `transpiler` really required - if you're the one to introduce it, it hasn't been used in all this time - do we need it?

Comment: @JonClements ["Source-to-source"](https://www.google.com/search?num=50&site=&source=hp&q=%22source-to-source%22&oq=%22source-to-source%22&gs_l=hp.3...394.4368.0.4497.21.13.0.0.0.0.464.1040.2-1j1j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..19.0.0.0.WI_odlF8APs) appears much more frequently than ["transpiler"](https://www.google.com/search?q=transpiler&oq=transpiler&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j69i65.1526j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) in Google's search results, so it would probably be a useful tag.